# How to use an If-else within an array in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4.

in `app/config/prod/app.php`

I have an array of things, laid out like this,

```
<?php

return array(

‘debug’ => “fault”

// and more ...

)
```

I want to set my `default` value to a different thing base on auth user type.

**IF** the user type is admin, I want to set the debug to true
**ELSE** set it to false.

Can I do an if-else check within an array  in PHP  ?

I’ve tried using ternary operator, but no luck. I hope I didn’t do anything wrong.

```
isset( Auth::user()->type == “Admin” ) ? ‘debug’ => “true” : ‘debug’
 => “fault”
```

Thanks for your help in advance ! :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Laravel. Learn PHP.

Answer (score 1):

What you can generally do is use the ternary operator for the *value* and not the full key value pair

```
'debug' => (Auth::user()->type == "Admin" ? true : false)
```

However, I'm not sure what is available when this config gets loaded (`Auth::user()` is probably not). Let me know if this works and I'll come back to you.

#### Update

A little test just confirmed my assumption. The `Auth` class is not available when config files get parsed. That means you will have to set the value afterwards. I suggest you leave the default to `'debug' => false` and use this if the user is admin:

```
if(Auth::user()->type == 'Admin'){
    Config::set('app.debug', true)
}
```

You can do this wherever you want as long as it's "early enough". For example you can use the global `App::before` (in `filters.php`)

```
App::before(function($request){
    if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->type == 'Admin'){
        Config::set('app.debug', true)
    }
});
```

Comment: Where exactly should I put them ? I tried both of your suggestion. I got [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/brbv5868ywly34x/1.JPG?dl=0). It's doesn't show any debug tips as it should.

Comment: Put the `App::before` in `app/filters.php`. And take a look at `app/storage/logs/laravel.log` there you can see your error message.

Comment: I did that, and it didn't work :(. Also, why do I need to see the log for ? Thanks :)

Comment: For the error message? the screenshot you posted is because debugging is turned off (`app/config/app.php`) you could also turn it on temporarily

Comment: My goal is to turn that on all the time as long as the `Auth::user()->type == "Admin"`, I don't think, it's matter because it's me. :)

Comment: Sure but to help you I need to know what error you are getting

Comment: I put [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iqlfl7auxt3qqv0/Capture.JPG?dl=0) in my `app/filters.php` and the code doesn't seem to execute. I still get the same result.

Comment: Ahh sorry.. big misunderstanding. I thought my code produced an error but you only sent me that picture because you were testing if debug messages show up...

Comment: Can you try to just do `Config::set('app.debug', true)` inside the before callback? To see if the `if` is the problem.

Comment: It's ok. It happen. Thanks for helping me. :)

Comment: What u mean by before callback on which function/file ?

Comment: The same code in `filters.php` that you already have but without the if statement around `Config::set`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67145/discussion-between-iggy-and-lukasgeiter).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new filter and then apply it to the routes you want to check.

```
Route::filter('check_admin', function()
{
    if( Auth::user()->type == 'Admin' ){
       Config::set('app.debug',true)
    }
});
```

Now, you can use your filter like this:

```
Route::get('my-url', ['before'=>'check_admin'],function(){
    // Do your route logic here
});
```